plotly-resampler with plotly offline figure
I created a simple PyQt app that basically reads CSV files and shows their data in a plot. I decided to display the figures using Plotly offline so I displayed them in a PyQt widget called QWebEngine by providing an HTML of the figure:
traces = self.prepare_traces()

layout = go.Layout(xaxis=dict(title=self.x_label, range=self.x_axis_range),
                       yaxis=dict(title=self.y_label))
self.fig = go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout)
self.update_figure_layout(self.x_label, self.y_label)

plot_div = self.render_plot_html()

return self.wrap_plot_in_html(plot_div)

where wrap_plot_in_html is like this:
return f"""
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body style='margin:0; padding:0; background-color:{self.data_handler.figure_bg_color};'>
        {plot_div}
    </body>
</html>
"""

So far everything works well.
However, I came to a situation where the data that I want to display is relatively big and every user interaction with the figure makes it lag and react very slowly.
I saw that there is a library called Plotly-resampler that basically helps with data aggregation based on the zoom level of the figure and more.
From the tutorial, all I need to change is basically:
self.fig = FigureWidgetResampler(go.Figure(data=traces, layout=layout))

So I tried it, and indeed the displayed figure seems to have some of the resampler features (for example I can see the [R] in the legend). however, it is not interactive. When I zoom the figure or anything, it won't really use the resampler as it should which makes some sense to me since I loaded the HTML of the initial state but I wonder if there is anything I can do to make it work.
Thank you

it won't really use the resampler as it should which makes some sense to me since I loaded the HTML of the initial state : exactly, by generating a static HTML view of the figure, the dynamic aggregation won't work as it needs to run in a backend callback. You would need the same feature but implemented on the clientside, which I think doesn't exist.

Is there any way I can use the show_dash() supported by plotly_resampler to load a dash app into QWebEngine and then have those features?

I think yes it should be possible, but I'm not sure of the end result. You would need to run fig.show_dash(use_reloader=False) in another thread (the flask reloader used by dash needs to run on the same thread), and make the QWebEngine browser loads the dash app from url directly (eg. http://127.0.0.1:8050). This post should help.
